# ListBox Button Firing Before SelectedItem Changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a `ListBox` in which its items contain a `TextBlock`, a `Button` and an `Image`. I have a `Click` method on my `Button`, but my problem is that it fires before the `Item` of the `ListBox` has changed. Here is the code for my `ListBox`;

```
<ListBox x:Name="imageListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding CCTVImageCollection}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CCTVImage}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PictureName}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Directory" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Click="OnDirectoryButtonClick"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Live Feed" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Click="OnCCTVButtonClick"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Source="{Binding PicturePath}" Height="400" Width="600" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

And the method that is fired after clicking one of the `Buttons`;

```
private void OnCCTVButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = imageListBox.SelectedItem as CCTVImage;
    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        Process.Start("chrome.exe", selectedItem.CCTVPath);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the method relies on the `ListBox.SelectedItem` and as this does not change when the `Button` is clicked the `SelectedItem` is dealt with as null and nothing happens. How can I enforce that the `SelectedItem` changes on the `Button` click?

Comment: @Paparazzi Could you elaborate I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Paparazzi I struggle to see how asking you to elaborate your comment should involve any research but I'll go away anyway. Is the user still going to have to click twice even if I check the source of the sender? Is there a way the user clicks on the `Button` and it instantly selects the item without them having to click once to select the item, once to fire the event?

Comment: Well I did look up the answer but now chose not to post.  Be nice and show some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you did not find any solution for the issue.

Normally during such scenarios, what I do is either disable the button until selection of list item or get the list item from the container where the button was clicked. Try this. It should work.

```
private void OnCCTVButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = ((ListBoxItem)imageListBox.ContainerFromElement((Button)sender)).Content as CCTVImage;
    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        Process.Start("chrome.exe", selectedItem.CCTVPath);
    }
}
```

You can also get the clicked list item by finding the visual ancestor from the visual tree during a button click.